# HTML/CSS/PHP Contact Form Not Submitting

Tags: php, html, css

I have a contact form on a website, I'm testing it live on the website and the submit button works when nothing is in the text fields, but when it's filled out it doesn't send. I've tried changing different things about the HTML like the method="post" to method="POST", I tried removing the noValidate="noValidate" from the  section. I tried changing $_REQUEST to $_POST in the PHP document. I'm kind of new to contact forms and PHP so it could be something simple, but I'd love to know what I did wrong.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="POST" id="contactForm" noValidate="noValidate">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  
                    <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'" placeholder = 'Enter Message'></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder = 'Enter your name'>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder = 'Enter email address'>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder = 'Enter Subject'>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm btn_4 boxed-btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

And here is contact_process.php:

```
<?php

    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $number $_REQUEST['number'];
    $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "This is a test subject.";

    $logo = 'img/logo.png';
    $link = '#';

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
    $body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
    $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
    $body .= "</tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    echo "Thank you!";

?>
```

Comment: $number $_REQUEST['number']; this line could cause syntax error. = is missing. Also, I don't see input[name=number] in your html

Comment: Where you testing/run your script?
it is in live server or your localhost system?

Comment: @Siddharth the website is published and I'm testing it on the live website, not the local files. Currently testing out PHPMailer as that was most likely the issue.